# Simplify a matlab expression to matrix form

Tags: matlab, math, matrix, refactoring

I have this function which normalize a matrix(basically multiply each element by a value), I was wondering how can I get rid of these two nested for loops and do it in all matrix operations?

```
function T = Normalize(trust, m)

T3 = sparse(trust(:, 1), trust(:, 2), trust(:, 3), m , m);
Outdegree = sum(T3, 1);
Indegree = sum(T3, 2)';



for i = 1:m
    for j = 1:m
        T3(i,j) = sqrt(Indegree(j) / (Indegree(j) + Outdegree(i))) * T3(i,j);
    end
end

T = T3;
end
```

Comment: What exactly were you trying to do? I think some sample input/output would go a long way. Also `n` is never used.

Comment: @LeanderMoesinger yes you are right, `n` is redundant, I have an adjacency matrix and I want to multiply each of its element with a combination of indegree and outdegree of each node

Comment: Did any of the answers work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

depending on how sparse your matrix is, migth not be worth it to vectorize.
for a very sparse matrix I would attempt to just use the non zero elements:

```
[i,j,s] = find(T3)
T3_ = sqrt(Indegree(j) ./ (Indegree(j) + Outdegree(i))) .* s
T3 = sparse(i, j, T3_ , m , m);
```

Hope thats what  you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Done it in paper:

```
outdegree = repmat(outdegree,m,1)';
indegree = repmat(indegree,1,m)';
T3 = T3.*(sqrt(indegree./(indegree+outdegree)));
```

Tested and it works for my example. Let me know if it works for you